# Не работает дефолтная картинка в модели Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, backend

Всем привет!

На моем сайте, основанном на Python Django, есть страница с профилем пользователя в которой отображается информация и его картинка профиля.

Модель пользователя:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    profilePicture = models.ImageField( upload_to = "profile_pictures/%Y-%m-%d", default = 'default.png')
    testInt = models.IntegerField(default = 10)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

До того как пользователь загрузил свою аватарку, используется дефолтная, расположенная в /media/default.png, однако при регистрации пользователя с последующим заходом в профиль картинки нет.

+ в admin ее тоже нет (c отображением картинок все в порядке):

[image: 1]

*TestInt использовал чтобы проверить, работает ли default в целом*

Еще следует обратить внимание на то, что регистрация происходит через **django auth user model**, а Profile - **OneToOneField**

В прошлой версии сайта, где вся информация о пользователе была в модели Profile (без использования OneToOneField с Django User все работало хорошо)

Я новичек в Django, поэтому извиняюсь за странные вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не нужно было такое поведение. Мне важно видеть что изображения нет. Да и расположение файла по умолчанию в media выглядит не совсем хорошо. `media` - это папка, в которую загружают файлы, на не помещают в ручную. Если вы соберетесь переносить/создать другой сайт основнный на этом коде, то он должен работать и без папки `/media`.

Типичным решением является проверка. что `if profile.profilePicture:` или `....filter(profilePricture__isnull=False)`

А подмену изображения выводите в шаблоне.

```
{% if user.profile.profilePicture %}
    <img src="{{ user.profile.profilePicture.url }}">
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'default.png' %}">
{% endif %}
```

А еще можете написать метод, который будет возвращать `url` файла, а также проверять его наличие в файловой системе, так как Django не знает о том что файл исчез, пока он не понадобится. Ну это на будущее